# Can Mathematica solve this exponential equation

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

My version (12.1.0.0 Student Edition) does not solve this equation:

```
Solve[Exp [-n^2/(2 m)] <= 3/4, m]
```

WolframAlpha finds the solutions, but only for integer n? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-n%5E2+%2F+%282m%29%29+%3C%3D+3%2F4%2C+solve+for+m

Comment: Try `Solve[Exp[-x^2/(2 y)]<=3/4,y]` because WolframAlpha seems like it treats w,x,y,z more like real variables and i,j,k more like integer variables

Comment: @Bill:  Fortran lives!

Comment: Take the Log of both sides and then Mathematica `Solve[-n^2/(2 m)<=Log[3/4],m]` returns a warning suggesting you try Reduce. `Reduce[-n^2/(2 m)<=Log[3/4],m]` returns solutions.

Comment: `Reduce[Exp[-n^2/(2 m)] <= 3/4, m, Reals]`